# Rails - geocoder: how to run ".near" method for multiple locations in the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geocoding, rails-geocoder

I am trying to use [geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) to find all objects within a certain radius. Below is an example from the official Github site:

```
Venue.near([40.71, -100.23], 50)
```

This query will return me all venues that is in the 50-miles radius from the given location (`40.71, -100.23`).

However, in my case, the model `Venue` (table `venues`) has these columns representing 3 possible locations:

```
- latitude1
- longitude1
- latitude2
- longitude2
- latitude3
- longitude3
```

How do I force `geocoder` to look into all these 3 locations? Here,
`Venue.near([40.71, -100.23], 50)`
instead of looking only into

```
- latitude1
- longitude1
```

I'd need to check all 3 coordinations (maybe the 1st coordination isn't within the given radius from `[40.71, -100.23]`, but the 2nd one might be - and in that case, it's a match). How do I achieve that?

Comment: A physical thing can have only one location. It sounds more like there's a missing layer, e.g., a (whatever) can have multiple venues, like McDonald's has multiple locations. As it stands now you'd likely need to do this manually, or create a minimal abstraction `nearly` etc. that wraps up a manual comparison.

Comment: Please see [Advanced Database Queries](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#advanced-database-queries) section. If you store multiple sets of coordinates for each object, you can specify latitude and longitude columns to use for a search: `Venue.near("Paris", 50, latitude: :secondary_latitude, longitude: :secondary_longitude)`

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Advanced Database Queries](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#advanced-database-queries) section.

If you store multiple sets of coordinates for each object, you can specify latitude and longitude columns to use for a search:

`Venue.near("Paris", 50, latitude: :secondary_latitude, longitude: :secondary_longitude)`

In this case you need to do 3 queries:

`Venue.near([40.71, -100.23], 50, latitude: :latitude1, longitude: :longitude1)`
`Venue.near([40.71, -100.23], 50, latitude: :latitude2, longitude: :longitude2)`
`Venue.near([40.71, -100.23], 50, latitude: :latitude3, longitude: :longitude3)`

Don't forget to remove duplicates.

Comment: Well, but if I do have 3 sets of latitude and longitude, can I still use it? It looks like I can only enter the secondary lat/lon.